# How to apply if condition to two different columns and put the result to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df2` and want to generate a new column called 'tag' based on a `if` logic on two existing columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NOTES': ["PREPAID_HOME_SCREEN_MAMO","SCREEN_MAMO",
                              "> Unable to connect internet>4G Compatible>Set",
                              "No>Not Barred>Active>No>Available>Others>",
                              "Internet Not Working>>>Unable To Connect To"], 
     'col_1': ["voice", "voice","data","other","voice"],
     'col_2': ["DATA", "voice","VOICE","VOICE","voice"]})
```

The logic and my attempt are:

```
df2['Tag'] =             
            if df['col_1']=='data':
                return "Yes"
            elif df['col_2']:
                return "Yes"
            else:
                return "No"
```

But I got a syntax error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a value with if-**statement**, which causes the syntax error.

There are many ways to do this, I provide one using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```py
trans_fn = lambda row: "Yes" if row['col_1']=='data' && row['col_2'] else "No"
df2['tag'] = df2.apply(trans_fn, axis=1) # apply trans_fn to each row
```

Comment: trans_fn = lambda row: "Yes" if row['col_1']=='data' or row['col_2']=='data' else "No"

df2['tag'] = df2.apply(trans_fn, axis=1)